# PHP Query to MySQL to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to write a **PHP** file for get user info from **MySQL** then parse it to **JSON**

So if I run link like site.com/Player/**GetFromName/Nickname**

So the script will get "**Nickname**" user info (Coins, Rank, Gems) from MySQL
For output a JSON

But I've no clue how to parse it.

Comment: what info you want ? You want retrieve info from MySQL ?

Comment: @Tony as said, in the database there are columns "name" "uuid" "coins" "gems" "rank" "ip" these info need to be encoded to json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
There are great tutorials about PDO (database-API from PHP) with MySQL. [This one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) is quite large but you should definitely take a look at it.
If you are able to get data from your MySQL database individually (!) you can proceed with the stuff below.

Create an array of the data you got from your query. For example:

```
$data_array = array("name" => $name, "rank" => $rank, "coins" => $coins);
```

Then you can use json_encode to get your JSON-string:

```
$json_string = json_encode($data_array);
```

There you have your JSON-string.

For more information about json_encode you can visit the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful, the variable (Coins, Rank) how can be taken from mysql, that's the last part for get it working,  thank you

Comment: @HAlexTM is that a question? If so so you need an explanation about mysql in PHP?

Comment: if you can, awesome :)